# What's rules to specify byte sequence for BOM?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I'm handling some file encoding stuff. When I learn [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), it says `The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`, then I find the [Code page layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is a table that contains many character encoding information. What I am curious is that if there are some rules for the BOM bytes sequence, I mean, why don't use `0xEE,0xFF,0xBB` or any other bytes sequence to represent UTF-8? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is specific to Unicode UTF (Unicode Transformation Format) encodings. It is the Unicode character `U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` encoded to a specific byte sequence according to the rules defined in the specific UTF that it is encoded in, same as for any other Unicode codepoint.  What makes the BOM special is that it is the first encoded codepoint at the front of the encoded text, so you can discover which UTF was used to encode the text, if not specified out-of-band through other means.

The BOM for UTF-8 is `EF BB BF`, for UTF-16LE is `FF FE`, for UTF-32LE is `FF FE 00 00`, etc.  They are all just different representations of the same Unicode codepoint `U+FEFF`.

Other encodings, like Windows-1252, which you link to, do not use a BOM and cannot encode that particular character, so there is no alternative "Windows-1252 encoding" of a BOM.

Comment: The *sole* purpose of a BOM is to specify the Unicode encoding and its byte order (hence the name), but being a BOM is not the *sole* purpose of codepoint `U+FEFF`.